# How to select layer in root?

Tags: photoshop-script

I need to select specific layer text in root. the root contents several things

group1,
group2,
group3,
text1,
text2,
text3,
group4,

I can select layers by array index inside group. but, how i can select text1, or other layer in root?

Answer (score 0):

**Use Layer Kind and getByName methods**

==> to get layers by its name use `app.activeDocument.layers.getByName("test")`

==> to verify that the layer is text layer you can use `app.activeDocument.layers.kind = LayerKind.TEXT`

for more information go through official [javascript reference](https://wwwimages2.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/photoshop-cc-javascript-ref.pdf)